# Regarding Bigquery datasetId and tableId

Tags: google-bigquery

```
            How do I get the datasetId and tableId from BigQuery. I tried to click the dropdown on the sidebar and copied the dataset info and table info,  Is there any way, I can query the datasetId and tableId?  but I got this error. I am using php client libraries to pull the BigQuery data.
```

How do I get the datasetId and tableId from BigQuery. I tried to click the dropdown on the sidebar and copied the dataset info and table info,  Is there any way, I can query the datasetId and tableId?  but I got this error. I am using php client libraries to pull the BigQuery data.

```
use Google\Cloud\BigQuery\BigQueryClient;

/** Uncomment and populate these variables in your code */
// $projectId = 'The Google project ID';
// $datasetId = 'The BigQuery dataset ID';
// $tableId   = 'The BigQuery table ID';
// $maxResults = 10;

$maxResults = 10;
$startIndex = 0;

$options = [
    'maxResults' => $maxResults,
    'startIndex' => $startIndex
];
$bigQuery = new BigQueryClient([
    'projectId' => $projectId,
]);
$dataset = $bigQuery->dataset($datasetId);
$table = $dataset->table($tableId);
$numRows = 0;
foreach ($table->rows($options) as $row) {
    print('---');
    foreach ($row as $column => $value) {
        printf('%s: %s' . PHP_EOL, $column, $value);
    }
    $numRows++;
}
```

I am getting this error.

```
 Google\Cloud\Core\Exception\BadRequestException  : {
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid dataset ID \"mc-data-2:Turnflex\". Dataset IDs must be alphanumeric (plus underscores and dashes) and must be at most 1024 characters long.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Invalid dataset ID \"mc-data-2:Turnflex\". Dataset IDs must be alphanumeric (plus underscores and dashes) and must be at most 1024 characters long.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "invalid"
      }
    ],
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems like mc-data-2 is your projectId and Turnflex is your datasetId but in your code, datasetId is being picked up as mc-data-2:Turnflex. I am not aware of the php coding but you need to modify something so that it picks the correct datasetId.

Answer (score 1):

According to [PHP Google Cloud client](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.134.0/bigquery/bigqueryclient) library documentation for  a proper [BigQueryClient()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-client-libraries#initialize_a_client) class initialization you might be requiring propagate `$projectId` variable. In case of any Biqguery data querying or discovering action aimed, you would probably leverage [query()](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/master/bigquery/bigqueryclient?method=query) method submitting Bigquery [Job](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/Job) with the particular custom query or explicitly define [dataset()](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/master/bigquery/bigqueryclient?method=dataset) and [table()](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/master/bigquery/dataset?method=table) as the target Bigquery location.

Confirming @Priya Agarwal presumption, I've checked the code snippet from your example and it works as intended. I've catched the similar error that you've reported, once I made connection with `$datasetId` variable exposed jointly with `tableId`:

```
$datasetId = 'datasetId:tableId'
```

instead of:

```
$datasetId = 'datasetId'
```